# Parallax scrolling doesn't take current position into account

Tags: javascript, positioning, parallax, scrolltop

I have an element in a banner that contains my banner text. I would like this element to scroll opposite of the rest of the site. Here is the element:

```
 <div id="parallax-banner" class="header-content-container">
        {{ widget_data.banner_content.html }}
    </div>
```

The css:

```
.header-content-container {
max-width: 680px;
text-align: center;
color: {{ lightFontColor }};
position: fixed;
z-index: 5;
left: 50%;
margin: auto;  
margin-left: -340px;
margin-top: -96px;
```

}

and the js:

```
document.getElementById("parallax-banner").style.top = '57%';

function parallax() {
    var paraScrollElement = document.getElementById("parallax-banner");

    paraScrollElement.style.top =- (window.pageYOffset / 15)+'%';

}

window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false);
```

When you load the page the element sits where I want it to. Once your scroll though it jumps to the top of the screen. The top position change on scroll from there so it is working how I want it to except that it is not taking the initial top position into account with the scroll event.

Comment: just make sure you call `parallax()` once, immediately after the page loads.

Comment: I don't understand how this will help. Doesn't the function need to be called every time a scroll event happens in or for the position to update? and the function is what is moving the element to the top of the page, so it this wouldn't solve the issue of the function not taking the current position into account...